# Adding AngularJS to existing node-express-mysql app

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js, gruntjs

I am new to AngularJS and would like to install it on an existing Node-Express-MySQL-Passport-EJS based app.

Where should I start? Do I have to install Grunt and Bower first?

I'm aware of the Mean.js stack but I don't use Mongo, my database is relational.

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular as is using the files. You can install it using "npm" or "bower" as well. https://github.com/angular/bower-angular

Grunt may be necessary if you want run any tasks to your app, any automation stuff like minification etc. Grunt is basically task runner.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is therre any advantage using bower and not npm? because I have npm already so would rather use it.
Also, I suppose there won't be a problem adding grunt later, right?